# Turn image SRC into background-image in jQuery

Tags: jquery

[How to set the image src using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183347/how-to-set-the-image-src-using-jquery)

I am looking to do the opposite of what this jQuery snippet does.  I need a bit of code that will turn

```
<img src="images/filename.jpg">
```

to become

```
<div class="imageBox" style="background:url(images/filename.jpg)"></div>
```

I've searched up and down trying to find something that will do this but have come up empty.  I'm no jQuery guru, so I would appreciate any help someone could offer.  Thanks

Comment: There was an answer posted earlier that seemed useful, but it has subsequently been deleted.  Is there a way to undelete it?

Comment: I can see the answer (10k+ rep), and you can trust that it was deleted for a reason

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("img").each(function(i, elem) {
  var img = $(elem);
  var div = $("<div />").css({
    background: "url(" + img.attr("src") + ") no-repeat",
    width: img.width() + "px",
    height: img.height() + "px"
  });
  img.replaceWith(div);
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/Fnwmx/)

Comment: +1 - Although you forgot the class - `<div class='imageBox' />` instead of just `<div />` should do the job nicely.

Comment: What is this function doing? I just don't see how this bit of code is outputting an inline background-image

Comment: @James It loops through each `img` tag, creates a `div` and sets the background image to the `src` of the `img`, then it replaces the `img` with the `div`.  Want a demo?

Comment: Sure.  I've been trying to get it to work in a big, complicated template, so maybe seeing it working on it's own would help.

Comment: @James Answer updated to include link to a live demo with three images.  It replaces them with `div` and sets the inner HTML of the `div` to the `alt` attribute of the `img`.