# How to efficiently change image attribute "src" from relative URL to absolute using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the `src` for an html image tag from relative to absolute url.

I am using the following code. urlRelative and urlAbsolute are created correctly  but I cannot modify the image in the last line.

What could be wrong wrong in my script?

```
..... // other code here

     request.done(function(resp) {
            var imgTags = $('img', resp).each(function() {
                var urlRelative = $(this).attr("src");
                var urlAbsolute = self.config.proxy_server + self.config.location_images + urlRelative;
                $(this).attr("src").replace(urlRelative, urlAbsolute); // problem here
            });
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: The replace method in Javascript returns a value, and does not act upon the existing string object. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: For absolute URL, you can just use: `this.src = urlAbsolute;`

Comment: jQuery("#my_image").attr("src", "first.jpg")

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(this).attr("src", urlAbsolute)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I am able to change the url for image but I need the resp to be update ... any idea how to implement this? thanks

Comment: yes in resp every element should be updated, more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868343/load-a-html-page-and-change-each-img-src-tag-updating-the-result-loaded

Answer (score 3):

Try `$(this).attr("src", urlAbsolute);`

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery("#my_image").attr("src", "first.jpg")
```

Answer (score 2):

used this code for src

```
$(this).attr("src", urlAbsolute);
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ekeru4)

Answer (score 1):

Your code can simplified a lot to

```
$('img', resp).attr('src', function(idx, urlRelative ) {
    return self.config.proxy_server + self.config.location_images + urlRelative;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of below code:

```
$(this).attr("src").replace(urlRelative, urlAbsolute);
```

Use this:

```
$(this).attr("src",urlAbsolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

The replace method in Javascript returns a value, and does not act upon the existing string object. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

In your example, you will have to do

```
$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

change image captcha refresh

html:

```
 <img id="captcha_img" src="http://localhost/captcha.php" />
```

jquery:

```
$("#captcha_img").click(function()
    {
        var capt_rand=Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) + 1);
        $("#captcha_img").attr("src","http://localhost/captcha.php?" + capt_rand);
    });
```